# ICollectionView Filter won't refresh - are my bindings wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, filter

I'm writing a program to view images, list them by their file name, and have a text box for searching that automatically filters the list as you type in it.

I can see the filter actually working - and it looks as if the refresh is firing too - however it does not 'refresh' on the screen.

**Code**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AllImages);
    new DynamicFiltering(collectionView, this.TextBoxFilter);
}

public class DynamicFiltering
{
    public DynamicFiltering(ICollectionView filteredView, TextBox textBox)
    {
        string filterText = "";
        filteredView.Filter = delegate(object item)
        {
            MyImages textvalue = item as MyImages;
            string textvaluestring = textvalue.Name as string;
            if (textvaluestring.ToUpper().Contains(filterText.ToUpper()))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        };
        textBox.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            filterText = textBox.Text;
            filteredView.Refresh();
        };
    }
}
```

and the xaml is

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFilter"/>

<ListBox Name="VisualList"
         Template="{StaticResource StandardListBox}"
         DataContext="{Binding AllImages}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         Width="Auto"
         Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Is the problem in the list box binding? Another thing perhaps noteable is i'm holding a string and imagesource within each object in my list.

---

EDIT:
Below is the code i use to populate AllImages - using Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures as a sample.

```
    public class MyImages
    {
        public ImageSource _image;
        public string _name;

        public MyImages(ImageSource image, string name)
        {
            _image = image;
            _name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _name;
        }

        public ImageSource Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

    }

    public List<MyImages> AllImages
    {
        get
        {
            List<MyImages> result = new List<MyImages>();
            foreach (string filename in
                System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)))
            {
                try
                {
                    result.Add(
                    new MyImages(
                    new BitmapImage(
                    new Uri(filename)),
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)));
                }
                catch { }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you include the definition for `AllImages`? What type is it? Also, I assume that when you launch your app, the full list of images is shown, but never filtered?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I have updated the original post to include the list AllImages. And yes, that's correct - whether i use a static filter or try to fanci-fy it a bit using one that updates on the text boxes content. However in code the filter does seem to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instincts are on track, the problem originates from your bindings. Your `ItemsSource` is not bound to the same view instance your filter is using. Try it this way:

```
    public ICollectionView CollectionView { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        DataContext = this;
        CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AllImages);
        new DynamicFiltering(CollectionView, this.TextBoxFilter);
    }

    <ListBox Name="VisualList" 
         DataContext="{Binding CollectionView}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         Width="Auto" 
         Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: Spot on mate, thankyou very much for this. I tried binding it to 'collectionView' instance originally, however it appears I had set the original up wrong slightly. Works brilliantly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling Refresh, just set the filter again.

Comment: Tying in with my response to another answer, I don't think the problem lies within the refresh, as much as a wrong binding. However I just can't determine any other possible ItemSource.

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling was right, the problem is in the binding of the Listbox. Remove the DataContext setting, and then set `ItemsSource="{Binding AllImages}"`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't fix anything - didn't appear to make any difference at all. I have tried setting a static filter without any updating from the text box (just feeding the filter a string) and again, when I step through my code it does appear to set the filters - as in it returns false and true depending on if it matches the filter criterea - however the displayed result does not reflect any filtering.

I feel like it is something even more obvious again, like i'm just not binding to the right thing at all, or I haven't set the CollectionViewSource right or something.